# WordPress Theme php fallback relocate

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Considering WordPress fallback mechanism, we know that we have to put files in the root directory of theme, assume that we have a custom post type named `gallery` and for that, need to create `archive-gallery.php` as a custom post type archive page to make it a custom view.

Now the question is, how can we move this `archive-gallery.php` file **outside of root** directory of theme, in sake of we are creating a plugin like gallery, and want to create a default view when user includes it, directly or as a plugin.

Also this can be used to have fewer files in theme root, specially when we have a custom organizing system, or using composer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can, you can use the template include hook

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'default_template', 99 );

function default_template( $template ) {

    if ( is_singular( array( 'cpt1', 'cpt2' ) ) ) {
        $template= '/path/archive-gallery.php' 
    } // also is_archive() etc...

    /*
        another method:
        $file = basename($template);
        $default_folder= '/path/';
        if(file_exists($default_folder.$file)){
            $template= $default_folder.$file;

        }
    */

    return $template;
}
```